# Macros for Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 23.04

I have recently started using Ubuntu 23.04 instead of Windows, and I am currently stuck trying to setup macros for my keyboard/mouse. In Windows I would use the Razer Synapse software to set up macros, but on Linux there is currently no support for macros (snake razer software does not fully support macros yet).

Thus I tried to install "AutoKey" but with no success. The main problem I encountered was that I was not able to add a hotkey. It seemed like as if the software was not able to read any of the keyboard inputs when assigning hotkey. I even tried the different versions of AutoKey (GTK and Qt) none of which worked.

As a result of my countless attempts to get this to work, I would like to ask if you (the reader) have any solutions to this? As I would like to simply perform a key combination like Ctrl + F5 (for example) and run some kind of script/command, for example performing a right-click x amount of times when y key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Open menu, search for "keyboard" and open it.

The tab "shortcuts" has an option "custom shortcuts". Create a new one and type "Ctrl+F5" as the shortcut and add your script at the "command" text box.

Comment: "menu" --i.e.--> "settings" ... I guess